# How to resolve "/bin/sh: 1: sshfs: not found" when trying to mount remote drive?

Tags: mount, ssh, fstab, sshfs, fuse

I'm trying to mount a remote drive on a server that I have SSH access to using fuse/sshfs

I created a mount point at /mnt/review/server and created the following entry in my fstab, as per [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs):

```
me@server:/    /mnt/review/dori    fuse.sshfs    defaults,user,noauto,idmap=user,allow_other 0 0
```

I've also tried a slightly different entry, based on the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS):

```
sshfs#me@server:/    /mnt/review/dori    fuse    defaults,user,noauto,idmap=user,allow_other 0 0
```

Each time, I just get `/bin/sh: 1: sshfs: not found` - nothing in the system logs.

This did work back when I was running Kubuntu 14.04 - I've since changed to Mint running on Ubuntu 14.04, and now I get this.

It seems like SSHFS is not installed - but I can't find anything helpful on Google for this message. I've also made sure the the `fuse` package is installed. I'm stuck for how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you using OpenSSH or an alternative like Dropbear?

Comment: openssh - never used anything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install sshfs before you go further.

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Now, you should test that everything is working correctly. You should try mounting your server with.

```
sshfs -o idmap=user $me@server:/ /mnt/review/dori
```

If that works, unmount the directory with

```
fusermount -u /mnt/review/dori
```

The use the second line you posted about from **/etc/fstab**.

```
sshfs#me@server:/    /mnt/review/dori    fuse    defaults,user,noauto,idmap=user,allow_other 0 0
```

Comment: d'oh - could have sworn I'd checked that package was installed - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you said sshfs wasn't installed yet, have you tried installing it?

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install sshfs`